Are vscode extension running in isolated process + have diff memory
I know that vscode extensions are running under the process of extension host.
I understood that because of that they share the same process.env variables.
My question are:

Does each vscode extension run in a separated isolated process?
Do they have separated memory?
3.Lets say i have a platform for creating extensions over vscode. A user creates 2 extensions. Good and malicious.
Can a malicious extension access some other extension (If ill create 2 extensions in my application) and get some important information? Where can I find some prof for that?

Thank you!
I tried to find some info about it in the vscode extension doc but didnt find a concrete prof for that.

Some experiments and tools like Process Explorer can guide you enough.

Hi , did you read the doc Our Approach to Extensibility?


1.Does each vscode extension run in a separated isolated process?2.Do they have separated memory?

Yes, from vscode-docs

VS Code loads and runs extensions in a separate process, the extension host process. A misbehaving extension cannot impact VS Code and in particular its startup time.

Our Approach to Extensibility

we do not provide direct access to the underlying UI DOM to extension writers. we run extensions in their own host process and prevent direct access to the DOM.


The approach to run the extensions isolated in a separate process allows VS Code to strictly control the API exposed to extenders.

Therefore, i guess extensions cannot directly access the memory space of other extensions because they operate within the confines of the VS Code Extension API.
